# finding the size of an array in python

Tags: python

```
for i in set(data['MovementNumber'].values):
 data2 = data.loc[data['MovementNumber'] == i]
 x = len(data2)
 print(x)
```

This for loop basically makes a cell array for the 83 trials I have. The issue im having is that when I use len for the cell array. i get the array with the length of the individual arrays. and i get this array:

'''

```
[957
280
305
217
204
321
228
291
341
245
381
177
284
410
226
279
270
241
302
235
260
218
207
202
261
370
288
210
243
199
282
184
223
191
205
228
244
213
164
230
226
245
197
303
187
239
242
267
250
221
271
218
208
225
248
334
215
462
321
319 
346
231
223
293
261
274
181
304
329
295
311
298
303
227
218
245
235
182
215
242
174
261
460]
```

I want the length of this array but when i try to use len(x) i get the following error

object of type 'int' has no len()

can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: It mrans your `data2` so the value in `data.loc[data['MovementNumber'] == i]` is an integer. And you cannot get length of an integer. Are you sure the value of `data.loc[data['MovementNumber'] == i]` is a container(`str`, `list`, etc)?

Comment: gotcha. I will look into ways around this but yes data2 outputs a container with str elements. this is what the first array element looks like in data2:          Time  ...                                           RobotVel
0    0.010000  ...  [0.0758416354656219, 0.10029411315917998, -1.4...
1    0.020000  ...  [0.0758416354656219, 0.10029411315917998, -1.3...
2    0.030000  ...  [0.0249298606067896, 0.0827747881412506, -1.31...
3    0.040000  ...  [0.0249298606067896, 0.0827747881412506, -1.17...

Comment: Can you write the whole error line. In which line this error appears?

Comment: yeah so my next input was to get the length of my output x (shown above) and for that i entered len(x) and the error that i get is this: 
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()